# Alternative gateway on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ethernet, gateway

I have one LAN card. I've divided it to sub interfaces. Is there solution to have different working gateways on this interfaces? I want when PC cannot reach to destination using first gateway it should go through secondary gateway. I use Ubuntu 14.04. Here is my interface config :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.25
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
gateway 10.0.0.88
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

#sub interface
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 10.0.0.26
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
gateway 10.0.0.99
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do routes. The routes work as gateways but they only work in a season, if you shutdown your computer, the routes disappear.
To do routes forever you need create a script with route comands and move to init.d:

> sudo mv /home/usuar/script.sh /etc/init.d/
>
> sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/script.sh
>
> sudo update-rc.d script.sh defaults

and to delete the sript

> sudo update-rc.d -f script.sh remove

then remove the script

> sudo rm /etc/init.d/script.sh

Comment: The routes works at gateway, maybe the failure is in gateways, hardware, conexion... a conexion problem it may be for a thousand things. Try to isolate the problem